# Extract table from web output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, string

I am able to pull a webpage into my code as a long string. Now I want to remove everything before a `<table>` tag, and after the `<table>` tag - so I only retain the table itself.

I am thinking about either using NSScanner, or regexp. Which do you think is more efficient/easier to code manage? The page may also (in the future) contain two tables, and I would want to extract each one (one after the other) for display in my view.

Any ideas?

And thanks in advance!
Kolya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - I used NSScanner.

```
// calling a service to extract the webpage as a string..
NSString *thewebpage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self getthewebstring]];
NSString *tmpwebpage = @"";

// Assign 'theScanner' to class NSScanner
NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tmpwebpage];

// find start of TABLE
[theScanner scanUpToString:@"<h2>Table Header</h2>" intoString:nil];
[theScanner scanUpToString:@"</table>" intoString:&tmpwebpage];
NSString *myTableOnlyData = [tmpwebpage stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];
```

This worked very well for me. 
Kolya

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use this code

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)stringFilter:(NSString *)targetString {

        NSScanner *theScanner;
        NSString *text = nil;

        theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: targetString];

        while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

            [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<table>" intoString:NULL] ; 

            [theScanner scanUpToString:@"</table>" intoString:&text] ;

           [tempArray addObject:text];

        } 

        return tempArray;

    }
```

the temp array will contain all the strings in table tag [got help from this site](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-remove-selected-string-between.html)